# How to map CTRL+q key press to CTRL+c event?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, shortcut-keys

How can the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>  key combination be mapped to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event?

My keyboard is mapped to programmer-dvorak and I would like to have the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>  events to be mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> key presses respectively.

Mac OSX has something called **[Dvorak - Qwerty](http://www.chimoosoft.com/articles/dvorak.php)** that does this.

> You may also want to try Dvorak - Qwerty which uses Dvorak for typing
>   but Qwerty for keyboard shortcuts like ⌘ (command) A. This can be
>   handy if you've memorized common command combinations like ⌘X,C,V (for
>   cut, copy, paste), etc by location on your keyboard,

So far, I've tried a combination of xbindkeys with xdotool without any luck.

```
#Dvorak Cut
"xdotool key --delay 0 --clearmodifiers ctrl+x"
    m:0x4 + c:52
    Control + apostrophe 

#Dvorak Copy
"xdotool key --delay 0 --clearmodifiers ctrl+c"
    m:0x4 + c:53
    Control + q 

#Dvorak Paste
"xdotool key --delay 0 --clearmodifiers ctrl+v"
    m:0x4 + c:54
    Control + j
```

I've also tried via XKB with the following entries.

```
// Ctrl+' for Cut
interpret apostrophe + Ctrl {action = Redirect(Key=<AB05>, modifiers=Control);};

// Ctrl+q for Copy
interpret q + Ctrl {action = Redirect(Key=<AD08>, modifiers=Control);};

// Ctrl+j for Paste
interpret j + Ctrl {action = Redirect(Key=<AB09>, modifiers=Control);};
```

But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `autokey-gtk`. If you set Autokey to run at login, it will sit in the background and monitor input from your keyboard and mouse.

**Example:** You stated you would like to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> act like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.  If you ask `autokey-gtk` to "press" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> is pressed.

To install `autokey-gtk` issue the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

After installation, you can access it through the Dash or by typing `auto-gtk` in a terminal. To set the key combinations that you stated above, do the following:

**Step 1**

```
Run autokey-gtk
```

**Step 2**

Create a New Top-Level Folder from *File* -> *Create* -> *New Top-Level Folder*

**Step 3**

Select Folder and create New Script from *File* -> *Create* -> *New Script*

**Step 4**

in the *# Enter script code box*, enter `"keyboard.send_keys(shortcut you desire to imitate)"`

**Examples:**

```
1. keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+c")

2. keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+v")

3. keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+x")
```

**NOTE**: repeat Step 3-4 for each hotkey you want to add

**Step 5**

For each Script you made click on the second **"set button"** next to Hotkey and enter your key combination that you will use to imitate.

In your case for the `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+c") script` you would type <kbd>Q</kbd> in the text box and `click on the Control button` and then click *OK*.

**Do this for each script, being sure to modify your hotkey of course.*

**Step 6**

```
Click on *Edit* -> *Preferences*
```

Select the check box next to `Automatically start Autokey at Login`

**This should accomplish what your asking for :)**

Answer (score 1):

```
"xdotool key --delay 0 --clearmodifiers ctrl+c"
    Control + q + Release
```

Source: http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/X/event_handling.txt
(search for 'Generating X Keyboard Events')