# How to remap combination of keys to combination of keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

On my laptop, I want to map

<kbd>menu</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> to <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>pageup</kbd>

so that scrolling in terminal can be easier.

It is not a duplicate of  [How to remap a key combination to a single key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85850/how-to-remap-a-key-combination-to-a-single-key)

Comment: If you chnage it even the individual mapping of each key is interchanged

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/106834/499035
This might work