# Configure Caps-Lock to make entering backtick easier

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have a Swedish keyboard and for me to type a backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>), I need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and type the tick key twice. I wonder if there is a way (using `xmodmap` perhaps?) to make <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behave like the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, but only require one press on the tick key?

The same problem applies to other characters like <kbd>~</kbd> and <kbd>^</kbd>.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out how to use `xmodmap` to achieve this behavior.

I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map CTRL+q key press to CTRL+c event?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103766/how-to-map-ctrlq-key-press-to-ctrlc-event)

Comment: Have you considered to use the _Swedish (no dead keys)_ keyboard layout?

Comment: I was recommended "Swedish (no dead keys) " by others as well but could not find the setting. After having searched through the menus 10+ times I finally figured it out and it's working very well :) I modified caps-lock to be a "compose key" so that I can still enter `é` etc.
Thanks for the suggestion!